How to eliminate memory leak in Nest.js?
I have a memory leak issue on server №1. Here's the situation: Server №2 makes a request to server №1, and server №2 returns groups. However, for some reason, these groups gradually accumulate in memory, and the dump file size increases. This happens only when a request comes from server №2. If I test just a simple request on server №1, the dump file size increases momentarily but then decreases.
Here's the code for fetching information about groups from the database on server №1:
Controller:
@Get('/getPartOfGroup')
    async getGroupsBatch(@Query('size') size: number, @Query('offset') offset: number) {
    return this.groupsFromVkService.getGroupsBatch(size, offset)
}

Service (where the database query happens):
async getGroupsBatch(size,offset) {
    const groups = await this.repository.find({
        take: size,
        skip: offset,
        order: { id: 'ASC' },
    });
    console.log(groups.length)
    return groups;
}

Request from server №2:
async getGroups(start, pass) {

try {
  const link = process.env['API_URL'];
  const response = await fetch(`${link}/groups-from-vk/getPartOfGroup?size=${start}&offset=${pass}`, {
    method: 'GET',
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch categories. Status: ${response.status}`,);
  }

  const responseData = await response.json();
  return responseData;

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
  this.logsServicePostsAdd.error(`getGroups`, ` ${err}`);
 }
}

Can anyone suggest how to fix this? Also, another point to note is that during the request from server №2, the dump file size increases, but the volume gradually decreases, although it keeps growing.
